# pass string to R shiny from JS

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have a 'callback' JS code in R shiny app that captures the row data on click. The 'callback' is part of datatable definition. Is it possible to pass that row data to Shiny from JS and display in a modal form? It's a nested datatable with child rows. Thanks

```
callback = JS(
    "table.on('dblclick.dt','tr', function() {",
      "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
      "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
      "      td = $(this),",
      "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
      "      rowIdx = row.index();",
      "      rowdata = row.data();",
      "      var fields = String(rowdata).split(',');",
      "      console.log(fields);",
      "if(row.child.isShown()){",
      "  alert( 'Contig:' \n + fields[14] );",
      "  } else {",
      "  alert( 'Contig:' + fields[14]);",
      "  }",
      "} );",
)
```

Comment: You need `Shiny.setInputValue` (google it and tell me whether you manage).

Comment: Thank you, I was able to figure this one out. I've been learning R shiny for the past couple of months mostly from your solutions on SO.  They've been a great help!